# Why does a test succeed in my sandbox but fail on my org?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have a test for a trigger that succeeds in my sandbox (which I just refreshed from my org), but fails in my org

```
@isTest
public class Test_T_Set_Fee_Type_From_C_Fee_Schedule{

  static testMethod void test_Update_Fee_Type() {
    //create a client
    Client__c client = new Client__c(First_Name__c = 'Joe', Last_Name__c = 'Tyler');
    insert client;
    //create a fee type
    Fee_Type__c fee_type = new Fee_Type__c(Fee_Type__c = 'Therapy');
    insert fee_type;
    //use the fee type to create a fee schedule for the client, including the amount
    Client_Fee_Schedule__c fee_schedule = new Client_Fee_Schedule__c(Fee_Type__c = fee_type.Id, Client__c = client.Id, Fee__c = 50);
    insert fee_schedule;
    //create a client encounter using client and fee type
    Client_Encounter__c encounter = new Client_Encounter__c(Client__c = client.Id, Amount_Paid_Fee_Type__c = fee_type.Id);
    insert encounter;
    // get the encounter record after its been updated
    Client_Encounter__c updated_encounter = [SELECT Amount__c FROM Client_Encounter__c WHERE Id = :encounter.Id];

    System.debug('------------------------------>' + encounter.Id);
    System.debug('------------------------------>' + updated_encounter.Amount__c);
    // check that the fee amount has been entered as the amount for the encounter
    System.assertEquals(50, updated_encounter.Amount__c);
  }
}
```

This test is for a trigger that runs before update on the client_encounter object that looks up the fee type that has been entered and gets the amount for that fee type from the client's fee schedule and enters it into the encounter.
The test fails because in my org updated_encounter.Amount__c = 0 not 50, in the updated_encounter.Amount__c = 50

Any clues or hints where to look appreciated.

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger Trigger_Set_Fee_Type_From_Client_Fee_Schedule on Client_Encounter__c ( before update) {

  for (Client_Encounter__c ce: Trigger.new){
    // if the amount for the encounter is null
    if (ce.Amount__c == Null){
      // if the fee type is not null and there is a client
      if (ce.Amount_Paid_Fee_Type__c != Null && ce.Client__c != Null){
        // look up the client's fee schedule
        List<Client_Fee_Schedule__c> cfs = [SELECT Fee__c FROM Client_Fee_Schedule__c WHERE Client__c = :ce.Client__c AND Fee_Type__c =  :ce.Amount_Paid_Fee_Type__c] ;
        //if the client has a fee schedule for this fee type assign the amount from the schedule as the amount for the encounter
        if (!cfs.isEmpty()){
          ce.Amount__c = cfs[0].Fee__c;
        }
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

The mysterious thing is that I added a couple of debug lines to try and figure out what is going on, and the test now passes ???

Ahah! I see that I also added or = 0 to condition that triggers setting the amount... that must have been the difference... amount must be being set to 0 when the client encounter record is created...

```
trigger Trigger_Set_Fee_Type_From_Client_Fee_Schedule on Client_Encounter__c ( before update) {

  for (Client_Encounter__c ce: Trigger.new){
    // if the amount for the encounter is null
    if (ce.Amount__c == Null || ce.Amount__c == 0){
      System.debug('----------Trigger_Set_Fee_Type_From_Client_Fee_Schedule on Client_Encounter__c--no amount->');
      // if the fee type is not null and there is a client
      if (ce.Amount_Paid_Fee_Type__c != Null && ce.Client__c != Null){
        // look up the client's fee schedule
        List<Client_Fee_Schedule__c> cfs = [SELECT Fee__c FROM Client_Fee_Schedule__c WHERE Client__c = :ce.Client__c AND Fee_Type__c =  :ce.Amount_Paid_Fee_Type__c] ;
        //if the client has a fee schedule for this fee type assign the amount from the schedule as the amount for the encounter
        if (!cfs.isEmpty()){
          System.debug('----------Trigger_Set_Fee_Type_From_Client_Fee_Schedule on Client_Encounter__c--fee->' + cfs[0].Fee__c);
          ce.Amount__c = cfs[0].Fee__c;
        }
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is going to be extremely difficult to help you without the trigger code. The test doesn't tell us a ton as to what is actually going on.

Comment: Agreed.  We cant troubleshoot why your assertions are failing unless we can see the logic you use in the trigger.  Please add the trigger code

Comment: What is the API version of your test class?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ce.Amount__c == Null || ce.Amount__c == 0){
```

this condition in the trigger governed whether the amount in the client encounter record was updated or not

the code that was failing did not have the or

```
if (ce.Amount__c == Null ){
```

so it must be that in my sandbox the amount was null for the new encounter...so it was updated...however, in my org, the amount must have been initialized to 0... so it was not updating

it's still a mystery to me why the sandbox and the org operate differently

thanks